# Why joining a 1 row 2 column table on 1=1 can be very slow?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle DB and facing a strange performance issue about temp table query.
I have query like below

```
with config as (
select ratio_A, ratio_B from config_table --this table only have 1 row
),
inv as(
select id, name, sum(qty) as qty
from inv_table --this table have >1M rows, after grouping, result have only 3 rows
join config on 1=1
group by id, name
)
```

after creating these temp tables I would like to get the result.

```
select * from inv
```

this query costs few seconds only.

```
select * from inv
join config on 1=1
```

if I add `join config on 1=1` to the query, it costs more than 1 hour.
What is the reason that joining a 1 row 2 column table on 1=1 can be that slow?
And how to solve this problem?

**Update**

After adding materialize hint, The query with `join config on 1=1` can finish in few seconds now.
Many thanks for your helps.

```
with config as (
    select /*+materialize */
    ratio_A, ratio_B from config_table --this table only have 1 row
    ),
inv as(
    select /*+materialize */
    id, name, sum(qty) as qty
    from inv_table 
    join config on 1=1
    group by id, name
    )
select * from inv
join config on 1=1
```

Comment: The block inv - is the on the fly computation of the sum(qty). It seems you have materialized the results of this block to a temp table, and then joined with a 1 row table (config).

Comment: Also can you explain what you mean by query costs 1 hour

Comment: inv and config are not "created" as individiual tables, they are a part of a query. You can't select from them afterwards.

Comment: You are giving the subqueries in the `with` clause the same names as the base tables. This is already a bad practice. Then: Are you saying that the aggregate query on the `inv` table (with > 10M rows) takes only one second? I don't believe that.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph many thx, after adding materialize hint the query is going faster

Answer (score 0):

After adding materialize hint, The query with join config on 1=1 can finish in few seconds now.

```
with config as (
    select /*+materialize */
    ratio_A, ratio_B from config_table --this table only have 1 row
    ),
inv as(
    select /*+materialize */
    id, name, sum(qty) as qty
    from inv_table 
    join config on 1=1
    group by id, name
    )
select * from inv
join config on 1=1
```